# Benefits of using Google Drive client over manual package upload

Tags: google-drive

I am using Google Drive for backup. I 7zip my work and upload to Drive via Web interface. I keep multiple 7zip files like DesktopApps.7z, WebApps.7z, Documents.7z, etc. What are the benefits of having a client application over manual zipped upload? If I installed a client I would still make those 7z snapshots so I can't see any benefit other than not having to manually zip and zip all those files. So, what are the benefits of having the Google Drive client installed instead of the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several benefits:

1. Primarily, if you have multiple computers, your two (or more) instances of Google Drive will automatically sync up in the background.
2. It would save you a step. Once the GDrive client is installed, you don't interact with it anymore. You simply manage the files in the Google Drive folder as you would in any other folder.  If you created your 7zip files directly in the Google Drive folder you wouldn't also have to fire up a web browser.
3. It is useful if you don't have a network connection (or the one you have isn't very good), for instance if you're working on a laptop and there's no wifi nearby. You can just create your files and forget about them. Once you restore your network connection your files will automatically sync to the cloud. Your method would require that you remember to upload the files once you've gotten back on-line.

But, hey, if your way works there's nothing wrong with that.